# How can I pass a variable using psexec?

Tags: powershell, psexec

I my trying to pass a variable server name to use it with psexec, so I have a variable $hostname and i'd like to do

```
psexec \\$hostname
```

When I do this I am getting an error. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What kind of error do you get? What you have there should work, provided `$hostname` isn't empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `psexec` something to run, e.g. `cmd` or `powershell`.

Comment: yes I understand but I cannot get passed the server variable

`psexec \\$hostname cmd` is not working

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the $hostname variable? if not then you have to use `$env:COMPUTERNAME` as Powershell is different to the standard CMD.

Comment: There'd be little point in using `psexec` to connect to the *local* computer, wouldn't it?

Comment: lol, of course, I must say I wasn't properly thinking when I posted that. :-) I still can't see where he's struggling though. Like you said if the variable is set then it should work

Comment: Yes the host name will be coming from a list so it must be a variable.

Comment: Try posting the whole script if possible as it would give people on here a better chance of understanding what you're doing and see what part of the script is going wrong

Comment: `$hostname = Read-Host 'Enter host name'
psexec \\$hostname cmd`

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar issue passing `$` variables into psexec cmds. You can use this in your case:

```
$hostname = Read-Host 'Enter host name' | psexec \\\\\$_ cmd
```

or for a list (and Powershell 7 - drop the parallel switch for 5.1 or 6)

```
$hostname = Get-Content "...list.txt" | Foreach-Object -Parallel { psexec \\\\$_ cmd }
```

Comment: Use code blocks to format the code (search for `code blocks on markdown`).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me at an elevated prompt:

```
$myhost = 'localhost'
.\psexec.exe \\$myhost cmd /c dir
```